# "Weighted" random order in Craft CMS

Tags: craftcms

I have a field in a channel called "weight" where the user can set a number between 0-1000. On page load I want to generate a random number between 0 and "weight" for each entery, and then sort the enteries based on these numbers.

How can I do this with Craft 2/Twig?

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like the part of code you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Create the random number:

```
{% set range = range(1, weight) %}
{% set numbers= random(range) %}
Random No: {{ numbers }}
```